# Renaming column which is designed as [col_name] in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, rename, alter-table

i had made a table with column:

```
[id_no]  int not null,
name varchar(20).
```

Now when i am tying to rename the column [id_no] to id using query:

```
sp_RENAME 'tbl_cust.[id_no]','id,'COLUMN';
```

I gets an error message.The question is, can a column be renamed which starts with brackets[col].

Comment: @chinna_82  ERROR MESSAGE :Msg 15248, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 215
Either the parameter '@objname' is ambiguous or the claimed '@objtype' (COLUMN) is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Does the column really have brackets in its name? Try this:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.tbl_cust.id_no', 'id', 'COLUMN'
```

EDIT: since the column does have brackets in the name, you'll need to put a second set of brackets around the column name:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.tbl_cust.[[id_no]]', 'id', 'COLUMN'
```

Comment: Syntax error parsing SQL identifier 'dbo.tbl_cust.[[id_no]]'.

Comment: see [http://stackoverflow.com/a/21169214/591097](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21169214/591097)